# How to extract data from MySQL INSERT ... SELECT query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code;

```
// tenant charge

$tenant_charge_date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$tenant_charge_date_updated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql ="INSERT into accounts_tenant_charge (
tenant_charge_date,
tenant_charge_payment_terms,
tenant_charge_tenancy_id,
tenant_charge_notes,
tenant_charge_total_amount,
tenant_charge_date_created,
tenant_charge_date_updated,
tenant_charge_created_by,
tenant_charge_updated_by
)
SELECT
tenant_charge_date,
tenant_charge_payment_terms,
tenant_charge_tenancy_id,
tenant_charge_notes,
tenant_charge_total_amount,
'$tenant_charge_date_created',
'$tenant_charge_date_created',
tenant_charge_created_by,
tenant_charge_updated_by
FROM accounts_tenant_charge
WHERE tenant_charge_id='" . $process_rtc_row['tenant_charge_recurring_tenant_charge_id'] . "'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error Inserting Tenant Charge Data into Database: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {

$tenant_charge_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

echo '<p>The tenant charge (ID: ' . $tenant_charge_id . ') has sucessfully been added to the system.</p>';

}
```

How do I access the value of the fields being selected? For example, how do I access the 'tenant_charge_total_amount' value so that I can use it outside of the query.

Comment: you can't. you're running an `insert` query. inserts never return any data, even if you're doing an `insert ... select from`. that select is internal-only, and does not return the values being selected to the calling query code.

Comment: You're right, I was overthinking it. I'll just use a new select query to query the database based on the $tenant_charge_id